# How to find control on page by id

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a simple way to find a control in ASP.NET by id (in any nested container)? Other than traversing whole controls tree.

Something like this example:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox() { ID = "textboxId"};
panel3.Controls.Add(tb);
```

And in other method/class:

```
 TextBox nameTextbox = MethodToFindControl("textboxId") as TextBox;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No ... You have to traverse all controls tree until you find the control then you stop traversing, your method (MethodToFindControl) shall be a recursive method that takes two arguments: the root container (most of the time its the page) and the id of the control to look for.

Comment: See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/06/recursive-pagefindcontrol.html for an example of a function

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to traverse tree (as mentioned in question - I'm searching for different method).

Comment: Well.. I think that this is correct answer (but I knew this method earlier), so I have to accept it:)

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use method FindControl as follows:

TextBox nameTextbox = (TextBox) panel3.FindControl("textboxId")  ;

Comment: That won't find a control in "any nested container", as the question asks.  FindControl is not recursive.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are not able to find the control using findcontrol declare corresponding td/panel as server control and then you should be able to easily find the required control within td or panel element.

```
DirectCast(tdMultiCnstrTypCode.FindControl("BBIMultiConsCode" & cnt + 1), DropDownList)
```

This approach is easier than traversing though all controls and child controls of the page.